# PHP NumberFormatter: No Decimal/Fraction Digits Unless Necessary

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm trying to get the PHP NumberFormatter class to output currencies like:

- `$2`
- `$2.99`
- `$2.50`

This *mostly* works:

```php
$formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
return $formatter->formatCurrency($price, 'USD');
```

Except for in the case of $2.50, it actually outputs `$2.5` (missing the trailing zero).

Is there some attribute configuration that will give me what I'm expecting?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in that does this. Format it with 2 digits after the decimal point, then remove `.00` with `str_replace()`.

Comment: I want this to be locale correct (hence why I'm using a proper NumberFormatter to begin with). For example, the French locale uses `,` as the decimal separator, so the expected output would be `2 $US`, `2,99 $US`, `2,50 $US`. There are also some currencies that don't use 2 fractional digits (eg: 0 or 3 fractional digits). I think any attempt to `str_replace()` all scenarios is going to be painful.

Comment: You can use `$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, 'your symbol);`